# How to populate a SQLITE3 Model with a TXT data file

Tags: python, django, models

I have this following models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class User_Language(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And this forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class file_upload_form(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

And this Txt data file, separated by tab:

```
Lucas Rezende   Python
Fabricio    Django
Pappacena   Python
```

I created this view that basically renders the html file to handle the Txt file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from forms import file_upload_form
from models import User_Language
from myfreecomm.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

def upload_file(request):
    ''' 
    This view handles the file upload 
    '''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = file_upload_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            filename = file['filename']
            f = open('%s%s' % (MEDIA_ROOT, filename), 'r')

            for line in f.readline().split('\t'):
                table = User_Language(user = line[0], language = line[1])
                table.save()
            return redirect('/success_upload/')

    else:
        form = file_upload_form()
    return render(request, 'upload/upload.html', locals())

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'upload/sucess.html', locals())
```

At this point I can't figure out how to make this Txt file, named `data.txt`, be inserted into table `User_Language`.

I tried looking at Google for the response but couldn't figure out how to complete it.

Could someone clarify this issue with me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you having problems? Inside your handle_uploaded_file function, you just need to iterate through the file and create a model instance for each line. What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The problem is that I can't actually figure out how to do it. Could you give me an example if it is not asking too much?

Comment: I am saying that because in the example I found in the internet, I thought this `handle_uploaded_file` was a built-in function... seemingly not, yeah?!

Comment: Take a look at django's fixtures

Comment: No, you need to provide it yourself - [here's the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files).

Answer (score 1):

First you should decide if you need to save uploaded file or not. If you only need to access uploaded file contents, you can access uploaded file's fileobject like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    doc_fo = form.cleaned_data['file']
    for line in doc_fo.readline().split('\t'):
        ...
```

UPD.

If you want to load it into db you should use [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) in your model, if your use django 1.6. If you use earlier version of django you should use [TextField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#textfield) in your model and encode/decode file contents with [Base64](http://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html)

Binary field in model:

```
x = ModelX()
doc_fo = form.cleaned_data['file']
x.file = doc_fo.read()
x.save()
```

TextField in model:

```
import base64

x = ModelX()
doc_fo = form.cleaned_data['file']
x.file = base64.b64encode(doc_fo.read())
x.save()
```

To fetch contents later:

```
file_content = base64.b64decode(x.file)
```

Comment: I need to load it into the database.

Comment: Added instructions on how to save

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple model, so you can do it at a DB level. This may not be best practice once your model evolves, but if you use south for migrations it might be ok.

So you should go to your console access sqlite and issue the following commands:

```
.separator "\t"
.import sample.csv user_language
select * from user_language; --> you should now have data here.
```

In my case the db file and the csv file were in the same folder.